# Perfect multiplier between two curved line

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

Let me give you the context, and what I am trying to achieve.
I am trying to automate the plotting between company earnings and stock price. 
For that, I need a ratio where company earnings * Ratio would give me a result close to my earning.

Right now I plot my earnings, I plot the company stock price over 15 years and I trial and error the ratio to find the one that would give me a plot close to my stock price

[image]

In the above ratio = 8 then 9 until 12 that give me the most satisfying result

My goal would be to automate that process and find a mathematical way to find the best ratio

Any Idea?

Comment: One of the simpler methods to do this kind of fitting is the Mean Square Error method. Basically, for one ratio over a given interval, calculate the differences between points of your red and blue graphs, square them, and sum them. The algorithm then tries to minimize this number. Don't expect to be able to do this by hand, though.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof I intend to use python to do it ... I will have a look at the Mean Square error method thx